# How do I keep my daemon open through ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh, daemon

I have been working on a http server which accepts connections and then based on the host name, loads up the right project from .so, generates the page the client is asking for, then sends them back.
Now that I have several working projects, I am interested in making them available to others but here is my problem :

I am connecting to my dedicated server through ssh, and starting my daemon from there, but after a while, the pages are no longer accessible because my program is no longer running.
I also get kicked by the server after a while. I wonder : 
How do I keep my server running ? Does the fact that I keep getting kicked out by ssh after a little idle time explains why my daemon is being shutdown ?

Thanks in advance to whoever will be able to give me some element of answer.

Comment: How are you starting the daemon?  You could also try running everything in a `screen` or `tmux` session so it's not relying on your ssh session

Comment: This solved my problem. I wish you left and answer so that I can upvote you Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are really daemonizing your process it should already be detaching itself from your ssh session, so I'm glad this worked for you, but there may be other steps that would make for a "more correct" answer to your problem

Comment: My problem was that I wasn't really sure rather or not my program was terminated because of the termination of my ssh session. Now I know it is the case, I can start working on a solution, while using this temporarily. I was making my daemon by running its init.d script. I thought it would make it independent from my ssh session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your SSH session times out SIGHUP was sent to the sub-processes forked from the current interactive shell. That's why the processes were terminated (server no longer running).

To avoid idle SSH connection being kicked by the server, set the `ServerAliveInterval` to send a request for response from server (e.g. `~/.ssh/config`)

`Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 30`

To avoid shell sub-process termination, refer to

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/348836/keep-the-running-processes-alive-when-disconneting-the-remote-connection/348921#348921
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect

In short, there are 3 options:

- nohup
- disown / setsid
- start the servers in CLI in `tmux` or `screen` session on the server

> NOTE: If the server instances are already properly daemonized, try looking at `monit` or `supervisord` to keep them running ;-D